# CPLEX in C++: Converting a LP to MIP

Tags: c++, cplex, integer-programming

I am a beginner in using CPLEX in c++. I know how to solve a simple LP using CPLEX.

I am wondering if setting variables as integer (as follows), causes CPLEX use the branch and bound method to solve the MIP or it just solves a LP and at the end rounds the resulted values to integer?

I define everything same as a LP problem except variables. This is how I set the variables :
IloIntVarArray Variables(env,LowerBound,UpperBound)

I really appreciate if you can help me or introduce a good tutorial for CPLEX in c++.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Declaring any of your modelling variables as integer will give you a MILP model. CPLEX will (usually) use B&B to solve such models. Check out the provided samples which are available in C++ as well as C#, Java,etc.